# Create anonymous type list by running sql query in Sqllite database for windows phone

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have to run a sql query in sqllite db and get anonymous result back.
I have written the below code.

```
    var userlist = new List < user_tbl > ();
    var userlogin = new List < user_login_history > ();
    string json = string.Empty;
    using(var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH)) {
    userlist = dbConn.Query < user_tbl > ("select * from user_tbl");
    userlogin = dbConn.Query < user_login_history > ("select * from user_login_history");
    var listcom = (from n in userlist join ul in userlogin on n.id equals ul.UserID select new {
        n.name, ul.LoginTime
    }).ToList();
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listcom[listcom.Count - 1]);
}
```

Now I want to write the join query in sql and get anonymous list of objects back.

I have tried with

```
var templist = (from n in dbConn.Query<object>("select a.name,
                                               b.LoginTime    
                                               from user_tbl a inner join user_login_history b on a.id=b.UserID")
                select new 
                      { 
                        n.name, 
                        n.LoginTime 
                      }).ToList()
```

Which is not executing. Can anybody help me out with this?
I am using Sqlite for this.

**I cannot use a new class for every query(joins)**

Comment: What's "not executing"? Error, exception, incorrect result?

Comment: when I am querying with object (below code)

Answer (score 1):

Create One model class as you aspect your select field as below :

```
public class YourModelClass
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }

    private string _LoginTime;
    public string LoginTime
    {
        get { return _LoginTime; }
        set
        {
            _LoginTime = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use below code spinet for get data:

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connection string))
{
    string query = "select a.name AS Name, b.LoginTime AS LoginTime from user_tbl a inner join user_login_history b on a.id=b.UserID";
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(db);
    cmd.CommandText = query.ToString();
    var result = cmd.ExecuteQuery<YourModelClass>();
}
```

AND **var result** final get result of your desire query.

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look at the edited question.

Comment: @tuhin i have provide same like this... You have generate general model class for your specific screen OR your operation... In my sample it may have more properties if required

Comment: is there any chance to get the list without creating any model? I mean like you did "YourModelClass" ?

Comment: @tuhin As i know there is no chance without model to get your select query field column values. Hope this is helpful for you.